# Can you use a ForEach on a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a lot of blocks of code like

```
        foreach ( KeyValuePair<string, int> thisFriend in this.names )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", thisFriend.Key, thisFriend.Value);
        }
```

where `this.names` is a `Dictionary<string,int>` and I'm wondering if there's a way to make this more compact without losing any efficiency (by intermediary conversions or whatnot). Can I do something like

```
this.Names.ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", f.Key, f.Value));
```

???

Comment: You could write an extension

Comment: The question title is a bit misleading. although my english is not good enough to come up with a good alternative.

Comment: Try downloading the Microsoft Reactive Framework Team's "Interactive Extensions" (Nuget "Ix-Main") as it has an extension already for this as well as a lot of other very good enumerable extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom extension method:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, Action<TKey, TValue> action)
    {
        foreach (var pair in dictionary)
        {
            action(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
    }
}

// ...

d.ForEach((s, s1) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{s} ({s1})");
});
```

Or even a more universal one using `IEnumerable`.

However, in my opinion, it doesn't bring any improvements. There are 3 lines of code and there is no way to do this shorter. Using `foreach` is convenient and readable. You can just stop defining the type explicitly. Use `var` instead - it doesn't worsen readability, but saves a lof of time:

```
foreach ( var thisFriend in this.names )
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{thisFriend.Key} ({thisFriend.Value})");
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that if I use `var` too often then I will forget how to deduce types myself haha

Comment: +1 for suggestion `foreach`, here is an interesting post about this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: @AbolishtheIRS That's what Visual Studio's _Quick Info_ is for :)

Comment: @AbolishtheIRS I prefer not to use `var` in my code :) However, `foreach` in `Dictionary` case is the perfect one - there is only one type and you actually know what this type is, why should you type `KeyValuePair<Type1, Type2>` every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate over keys collection (but you have to convert `KeysCollecton` to list first)

```
this.Names.Keys.ToList().ForEach(k => Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", k, this.Names[k]));
```

This is definitely more concise, but not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This would also be possible for the Dictionary itself: `this.Names.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}",i.Key,i.Value));`